# Как отлкючить перенаправление на сайт CRM при отправке формы?

Tags: wordpress, post, crm

Есть WireCRM, в нее можно отправлять методом POST запросы. Суть в том, что когда я вставляю в WordPress этот HTML код, он отправляет всю информацию мне в WireCRM - происходит редирект на сайт CRM и пишет, отправлено.

Как сделать так, чтобы редиректа не было? Чтобы после нажатия кнопки отправить, открывалась страница на WordPress с моей надписью, отправлено.

```
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
<!--  ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ. Добавьте элемент <META> на страницу <HEAD>.  При            -->
<!--  необходимости измените параметр charset, позволяющий указать            -->
<!--  кодировку HTML-страницы.                                                -->
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->

<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
<!--  ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ. Добавьте элемент <FORM> на страницу.                        -->
<!--  Если вы хотите, чтобы после отправки вашей формы                        -->
<!--  происходил редирект, то заполните скрытое поле retURL.                  -->
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->

<form action="https://wirecrm.com/webtolead/do?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">

<input type=hidden name="id" value="4072">
<input type=hidden name="retURL" value="">

<label for="firstname">Имя</label><input  id="firstname" maxlength="40" name="firstname" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="lastname">Фамилия</label><input  id="lastname" maxlength="80" name="lastname" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="phone">Телефон</label><input  id="phone" maxlength="80" name="phone" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="email">Адрес эл. почты</label><input  id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="company">Компания</label><input  id="company" maxlength="40" name="company" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Сейчас в WireCRM изменилась работа с формами сбора данных, она была улучшена. Теперь есть возможность добавлять неограниченное количество форм, указывать ответственного формы, активировать и деактивировать формы, добавлять URL переадресации (Теперь это можно делать динамически в любой момент вы можете как указать, так и отказаться от URL перенаправления, если он не будет указан, то будет произведен редирект на сайт WireCRM, если укажите, то редирект будет на любую указанную вами страницу). Приведенный вами код сейчас будет неработоспособным, его требуется заменить на новый, на странице https://wirecrm.com/webtolead.

Вот скриншот настройки форм. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]